# How do I extract or locate pixels of a certain color within an Uint8List?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function that returns an image data as `Uint8List`. The image can be viewed using `Image.memory()`.

The pixels within  the image are color coded to certain values. [They are output from a segmentation network]

Rather than just color the detected/recognized pixels in the output image I want to extract those individual pixels. There are pixels that have been colored in the output image using the color: `Color.fromARGB(255, 64, 0, 0).value`.

I want to extract only the pixels having this color. How would I go about extracting these selected pixels from the `Uint8List` ?

Comment: Unless the image is in a bitmap format, good luck getting readable pixel data directly from the bytes.

Comment: @Abion47 Why do you say that? `image` package and `dart:ui` have encoding/decoding implemented already.

Comment: You are asking how to get the pixel data directly from the `Uint8List` that you retrieved from your function. This is prior to any of the decoding methods implemented in `Image`, so you are still stuck with encoded binary data. So unless that binary data is encoded in a format that stores the pixel data as plain bytes, you aren't going to get any usable pixel data from your list directly. You need to decode it first.

Comment: @Abion47 So it's decoding. Not a huge deal since it's already implemented.

Comment: [Indeed.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/decodeImageFromList.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `package:image/image.dart`'s `getBytes()`
Working demo change image `pixel` red to 0, you can see effect below
code snippet

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;
...
Future<img.Image> _changeImage() async {
    var response = await http.get('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9');
    Uint8List bytes = await response.bodyBytes;
    img.Image image = img.decodeImage(bytes);
    var pixels = image.getBytes();
    for (int i = 0, len = pixels.length; i < len; i += 4) {
      /*print(
          "r ${pixels[i]} g ${pixels[i + 1]} b ${pixels[i + 2]} a ${pixels[i + 3]} ");*/

      pixels[i] = 0;
    }

    return image;
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  Future<img.Image> _future;

  Future<img.Image> _changeImage() async {
    var response = await http.get('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9');
    Uint8List bytes = await response.bodyBytes;
    img.Image image = img.decodeImage(bytes);
    var pixels = image.getBytes();
    for (int i = 0, len = pixels.length; i < len; i += 4) {
      /*print(
          "r ${pixels[i]} g ${pixels[i + 1]} b ${pixels[i + 2]} a ${pixels[i + 3]} ");*/

      pixels[i] = 0;
    }

    return image;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _future = _changeImage();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.network("https://picsum.photos/250?image=9"),
            FutureBuilder(
                future: _future,
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<img.Image> snapshot) {
                  switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                    case ConnectionState.none:
                      return Text('none');
                    case ConnectionState.waiting:
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    case ConnectionState.active:
                      return Text('');
                    case ConnectionState.done:
                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Text(
                          '${snapshot.error}',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                        );
                      } else {
                        return Image.memory(img.encodePng(snapshot.data));
                      }
                  }
                }),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _changeImage,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, this is exactly what I was aiming to achieve  :)